# Update table data by keeping only newest modification date and time of records w/ no duplicates

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, compare

I have the following SQL query which keeps track of item price, date, and time of price change and keeps the values in a table named `dbo.NewPriceLabel`.

I am trying to make it keep only the latest modification based on the modification date and time and remove older values for the same primary key. The pk is the `PLU`.

Here is my current query:

```
USE [ItemTable]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[NewPriceLabel]    Script Date: 05/07/2016 03:46:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewPriceLabel](
    [PLU] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](40) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Sizes] [varchar](7) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OldPrice] [real] NULL,
    [NewPrice] [real] NULL,
    [Datechange] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [NewPriceLabel_Datechange]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_NewPriceLabel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [PLU] ASC,
        [Datechange] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

Comment: So you need a trigger which will delete older records when new row with same PLU is inserted?

Comment: The "query" in your question is just the table DDL.  If the purpose of the table is to keep only the row with the most recent Datechange, you should remove Datechange from the primary key so that there is only one row per PLU, You could then use a `MERGE` statement to insert if it doesn't yet exist and update only when the Datechange is later than the current value.

Comment: @gofr1: thank you. Could you show me a sample script of this trigger

Comment: @DanGuzman: Can you help me with this MERGE Statement by writing the script. Thanks

Comment: @gofr1: I am getting the following error when using this trigger: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TRG_AFTER_INS_UPD, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: @gofr1: Thanks. It works but it still shows duplicate records in two rows. Before it was more than two rows duplication of the same PLU (pk) with diffrent Datechange

Comment: Did you update or insert something new with same PLU?

Comment: @gofr1: yes, to test the trigger

Comment: @gofr1: Thank You for your help. It is working now as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger which will delete older records when new row with same PLU is inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_AFTER_INS_UPD
ON yourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    DELETE y
    FROM yourTable y
    INNER JOIN inserted i 
        ON i.PLU = y.PLU AND i.Datechange > y.datechange
```

Comment: Well, I don't see any END in my query.. Drop that trigger and create new. On the bottom add GO. CHANGE yourTable on actual name.

Comment: I made the correction and recreated the trigger but I am still getting duplicate values. I am trying to delete all duplicate an keep only the most recent record value

Comment: My pleasure! If my answer help, feel free to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is to maintain only one row per `PLU`, I suggest you remove the `Datechange` from the primary key and perform a one-time delete to remove existing duplicates:

```
--one-time delete
WITH dups AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PLU ORDER BY Datechange DESC) AS RowNum 
    )
DELETE FROM dups
WHERE RowNum > 1;

--remove Datechange from primary key
ALTER TABLE dbo.NewPriceLabel
    DROP CONSTRAINT PK_NewPriceLabel;
ALTER TABLE dbo.NewPriceLabel
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_NewPriceLabel PRIMARY KEY (PLU);
```

If your incoming data includes a `Datechange` value and you want to update the existing row only when the new `Datechange` is newer than the current value, consider `MERGE`,  Below is an example.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.MergeNewPriceLabel
     @PLU varchar(25)
    ,@Description varchar(40)
    ,@Sizes varchar(7) 
    ,@OldPrice real 
    ,@NewPrice real 
    ,@Datechange datetime
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--source PLU with a Datechange older than current one are ignored
MERGE dbo.NewPriceLabel AS target
USING (
    SELECT 
          @PLU AS PLU
        , @Description AS Description
        , @Sizes AS Sizes
        , @OldPrice AS OldPrice
        , @NewPrice AS NewPrice
        , @Datechange AS Datechange
    ) AS source ON
    source.PLU = target.PLU
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
    INSERT (
          PLU
        , Description
        , Sizes
        , OldPrice
        , NewPrice
        , Datechange)
    VALUES (
          @PLU
        , @Description
        , @Sizes
        , @OldPrice
        , @NewPrice
        , @Datechange
    )
WHEN MATCHED AND source.Datechange >= target.Datechange THEN
    UPDATE SET
          PLU = source.PLU
        , Description = source.Description
        , Sizes = source.Sizes
        , OldPrice = source.OldPrice
        , NewPrice = source.NewPrice
        , Datechange = source.Datechange;
GO
```

If you have no `Datechange` in the source data and simply want to insert the row if it doesn't already exist and update if exists:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.MergeNewPriceLabel
     @PLU varchar(25)
    ,@Description varchar(40)
    ,@Sizes varchar(7) 
    ,@OldPrice real 
    ,@NewPrice real 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--assume source PLU data is newer than current row and update Datechanged with current timestamp
MERGE dbo.NewPriceLabel AS target
USING (
    SELECT 
          @PLU AS PLU
        , @Description AS Description
        , @Sizes AS Sizes
        , @OldPrice AS OldPrice
        , @NewPrice AS NewPrice
    ) AS source ON
    source.PLU = target.PLU
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
    INSERT (
          PLU
        , Description
        , Sizes
        , OldPrice
        , NewPrice
        )
    VALUES (
          @PLU
        , @Description
        , @Sizes
        , @OldPrice
        , @NewPrice
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
          PLU = source.PLU
        , Description = source.Description
        , Sizes = source.Sizes
        , OldPrice = source.OldPrice
        , NewPrice = source.NewPrice
        , Datechange = SYSDATETIME();
```

Also, I suggest you avoid `real` and `float` types for storing currency values because these data types are approximate and cannot store all decimal values.  Use `decimal`, `numeric`, `money`, or `smallmoney` instead.

Comment: I am getting the following error when using your query: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MergeNewPriceLabel, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MergeNewPriceLabel, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: @Fadhl, what version of SQL Server are you using?  Please add the appropriate tag.  `MERGE` was introduced in SQL Server 2008 and will not work in SQL 2005 and earlier versions.